# clear focus on content when navigation drawer is showed

Tags: android, focus, navigation-drawer

What would be the best way to clear the focus in an android activity having a navigation drawer.

The problem it's that when the user has a textbox selected, if you open the navigation drawer the back event it's not consumed by the drawer, and the navigation goes back one step leaving the drawer opened.

Right now I solved using this on the activity, but i would like to know if someone use another solution where i don't need to use the ActionBarDrawerToggle events.

```
/** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    View window = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    window.clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a clean solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed it seems the drawer doesn't have focus when it's opened so it's `onKeyUp` won't be called. I checked this in the host activity and in `onBackPressed` `DrawerLayout#hasFocus()` returns false if the activity has a view that gained focus - an EditText or something else.

I even tried to mess up with its `descendantFocusability` property and that didn't work. I managed to fix this with a similar approach as you did: the drawer layout is requesting the focus:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

You are clearing the focus from content ViewGroup, but I am not sure who gets the focus then, most probably no view. 
Honestly speaking, this seems to me a bug in DrawerLayout as if it's opened, it should have the focus gained.