# Get the Support Library of a previous revision

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

My IDE is Eclipse. Due to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216088/drawer-layout-not-closing-on-back-pressed-depending-on-support-v4-lib) problem I would need to mount the Android Support Library revision 19 (instead of the current revision 20) for my project.

Where can I find it?

Comment: Short answer - its probably located somewhere on the internet. Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `<android_sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4`. There are different revisions of support library. Pick the one you need. Most likely yours is `19.0.1` or `19.0.0`.

To use it in Eclipse you need to extract corresponding aar-file, which is a zip file. There will be file called `classes.jar`. This is the library you need. Rename it into something more meaningful and copy into your project's `libs` folder.